# vuetable-2 in VueJs doesn't fetch data from parent component

Tags: datatables, vuejs2

Issue is the following:
I use vuetable-2 package (https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) for tables formatting and pagination.
The standard way to fetch data is to use "api-url" prop and to define exact pass:

```
<template>
  <vuetable ref="vuetable"
    api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
    :fields="['name', 'email', 'birthdate']"
  ></vuetable>
</template>
```

But what if I want to fetch data from data() function. Something like this:

```
data() {
    return {                       
           users: [],
           }
       }
```

So first I want to fetch data, using xhttp request with method:

```
getUsers() {                    
                this.$http.get(hostname + 'name=person_list&session_id=' + sessionApiId).then(response => {
                    this.users = connectionService.renderMultipleInstances(response.body);
                }, response => {
                    // error callback
                });
            },
```

The data need to be formatted using connectionService Class.

Then I need to pass it to the table, but nothing is passed, however in documentation (https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/wiki/Vuetable-Data) stated the following:

> tableData In api-mode, this stores the data that returned from the
>   server after the sucessful AJAX request. Otherwise, it stores the data
>   assigned to via data prop or setData method. Vuetable always use
>   tableData for table rendering.

How to pass users to vuetable.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the document here:
https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/blob/develop/docs/Vuetable-Properties.md#-http-fetch-v17

Template:

```
<template>
  <vuetable ref="vuetable"
  :http-fetch="getUsers"
  :fields="['name', 'email', 'birthdate']"
></vuetable>
</template>
```

Script

```
methods: {
  getUsers() {
   ...
  },
}
```